# Why is cursor is flickering during drag&drop in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dragula

I have a simple list of items that I want to reorder using drag and drop. I am using dragula to do that.

Everything is just fine when I use Chrome, but when I test it in IE11 my cursor is flickering while dragging when I am over text fields. Can someone explain me why and how can I avoid this?

Here is the snippet:

```js
dragula([document.querySelector('.draggable-container')]);
```

```css
.gu-mirror {
  position: fixed !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.gu-hide {
  display: none !important;
}
.gu-unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none !important;
  -moz-user-select: none !important;
  -ms-user-select: none !important;
  user-select: none !important;
}
.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.draggable-item {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
input {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}
.handle {
  cursor: move;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.6.8/dragula.min.js"></script>
<ul class='draggable-container'>
  <li class="draggable-item">
    <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
  <li class="draggable-item">
      <span class="handle">&#x2195;<span><input type="text">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue...

Comment: No, unfortunatelly I didn't

Comment: Try changing your margin to a padding instead. IE11 seems to not like margins for dropping.

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/303